# graph search api no returning my public post

Tags: api, facebook-graph-api, graph

I am using graph search api to search a public post posted for me on my wall. Example:

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=awstdw&type=post

My post contains the keyword "awstdw".

The above search not returning my post and this is a public post.

What's the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You might need to wait for Facebook to update the cache on this term. It would show nothing if you happened to search for the term before posing something that contained it.

If you try: https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=facebook&type=post you will that it does work. Try creating a new post with a different keyword, and then try searching for it, e.g.
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=asdasd&type=post

Comment: Thanks for the response.

After 24 hours I try to run again "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=awstdw&type=post" and the search not returning my post.

Comment: if I search "https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=awstdw&type=post" with a friend user, the search returning data. But if i search other public wall post with this friend user, the search not returning data.


any idea?